# What does "window = qobject_cast<QWindow *>(root)" mean?

Tags: qt

I have some code that works but I don't understand the meaning of this pattern:

```
QWindow * window;
if (window = qobject_cast<QWindow *>(root))
  window->show();
```

Comment: Did you check out [`qobject_cast`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#qobject_cast) in the docs?

Answer (score 3):

`qobject_cast` is Qt's alternative of `dynamic_cast` for `QObject`-based classes. `root` is a pointer to some object. In your case it probably has `QObject*` or `QWidget*` type. However, the code expects that it may in fact be a `QWindow*` object. `qobject_cast` checks if the object is an instance of `QWindow` class or any class inherited from it, and returns 0 if that's not the case. If the check is successful, `qobject_cast` returns `QWindow*` pointer to the object, and the code can use it to call `QWindow`-specific methods that are not available through `QObject*` or `QWidget*` pointer.

Answer (score 0):

The code translates to the following pseudo-code:

```
if (root is an instance of `QWindow` set window to that instance)
  show that window;
```

The `qobject_cast` works exactly like `dynamic_cast`, but only applies to `QObject`-derived classes and works even when runtime type information is not available (e.g. for small builds on MSVC, or on some embedded platforms).